# Const String From Settings

Tags: c#, settings, constants

I would like to set a const string from Settings.

In case I would like to change in the future the program language, it is quite easy;
Just have to modify the appropriate settings!

When trying this:

```
private const string constString =   
              "-&" + Properties.Settings.Default.constStringText;
```

I get this error:

```
The property or indexer 'Properties.Settings.Default'  
cannot be used in this context because it lacks the get accessor.
```

Any idea?

Comment: Does the `Default` property have _only_ a setter?

Comment: @ChrisSinclair The settings handles this and Default has getter : 'public static Settings Default {
   get {
    return defaultInstance;
   }
  }'

Comment: (Regarding your comment in the deleted answer that you are planning to use this for method parameter default values) Then you simply have to alter your code a bit. Default values _must_ be constants. You _cannot_ set constants from a configuration file. Try using method overloading instead where the overloads that don't specify those parameters wrap it with those default values.

Comment: A constant field should be initialized with compile-time constant value. You cannot initialize it at a runtime.

Comment: I have seen this, in spite of there being a getter, for argument defaults as well, in MSVS 2013, – but at least it also reports “_Default parameter value for '__<argname>__' must be a compile-time constant_”.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you intend to use this as the default value for an optional method argument, that is:

```
public void Foo(string something = constString)
{
    //do something
}
```

This `constString` *must* be a *compile-time constant*. From [the MSDN page for "Named and Optional Arguments"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx):

> A default value must be one of the following types of expressions:
>
> - a constant expression;
> - an expression of the form new ValType(), where ValType is a value type, such as an enum or a struct;
> - an expression of the form default(ValType), where ValType is a value type.

As such, there really is no way to read a value from a configuration file at runtime then use it for an *optional argument*.

One workaround would be to instead declare your `constString` as a `readonly` field:

```
private readonly string constString =   
              "-&" + Properties.Settings.Default.constStringText;
```

Then make your optional argument required and create a wrapping *overload* for your method that doesn't take that parameter. That overload in turn calls the old method with the default value resolved at runtime:

```
public void Foo(string something) //no longer optional
{
    //do something
}

public void Foo()
{
    Foo(constString); //calls the other overload with the default value
}
```

Comment: An alternative workaround – if overloading seems like too much clutter – is to make the default value in the argument list `null`, and apply the ‘real default’ (`constString`) in the implementation of `Foo`.

Comment: @PJTraill: You mean do a check that if the argument is `null`, set it to the configuration value instead? That is `if(something == null) something = Properties.Settings.Default.constStringText;`? One definitely could do that, although you start introducing magic values (you would have to document/know that `null` will pull the special config value), and would only work assuming that `null` isn't a valid input in the first place.

Comment: That’s what I meant, or use `something != null ? something : constStringText` somewhere. (I have never tried assigning to an argument.) It certainly has its downsides; the meaning of `null` __really should__ be in the documentation comments — but if you have several such arguments the overload route is also bad news. Overloads with many arguments are also a bore, as then the source is swamped by documentation comments between little bits of code!

Answer (score 1):

This error is in 99% of cases related to a wrong namespace.
You've probably generated some class in which you are using `Properties.Settings.Default`

Solution: check namespace in that class file. It must be the same as the name of the tag in App.config (Web.config) where that particular setting is stored.

Comment: I am not convinced, I have certainly had this without namespaces being involved, and the _<del>message makes perfect sense</del>_ initial value is certainly unacceptable if `constString` is not evaluated till run-time, as explained in Chris Sinclair’s answer.

Answer (score 1):

While [Chris Sinclair’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22961728/4847772) (a `const` member must have value type and be evaluable at compile-time, so use `readonly`) is correct, I should like to explain these restrictions and answer the implicit question what the compiler message means, albeit with the disappointing remark that seems to be simply an **error in the compiler**.

#### The error message

> The property or indexer 'Properties.Settings.Default' cannot be used in this context because it lacks the get accessor.

This message suggests that the expression `Properties.Settings.Default` could be made acceptable by adding a getter (and maybe something else) — as far as I know, that is simply wrong. After all, on the one hand, as the asker assured us<sup>1</sup>, there was a getter, and on the other, as Chris explains, the reason the expression is invalid is that is not evaluable at compile-time, and never can be, given that it depends on the run-time configuration.

Presumably this message is intended for other situations, and has been used here by mistake.

<sup>1</sup> I have also seen this, in MSVS 2013, when a default parameter value referred to a property which did have a getter – but at least it also reported “*Default parameter value for '`<parname>`' must be a compile-time constant*”.

#### The restriction to value types

The restriction of `const` members and default parameter values to value types (as at the C# 5.0 Language Specification, 2012) appears to be **not** entirely **inevitable**, but an understandable consequence of other language design decisions.

- A reference type can have a constructor evaluable at compile-time, but this is not supported ; perhaps this is because the language offers no way of indicating that a referenced object is immutable, nor even the concept of immutability of reference type objects. (Remember: an immutable reference to an object need not be a reference to an immutable object!)
- Delegate values referring to `static` methods can also be considered fully determined at compile-time, as would those bound to immutable objects, were that concept supported.
- Immutable arrays as constant values sound fairly easy to support.
- Constant members¹ and (*I believe*)² default parameter values are specified to be **part of the ‘interface’** of the class, in the sense that their values are to be determined at compile time and hard-coded into generated code using that class.

#### Resolution of the problem

- You can use **(** `static` **)** `readonly constString` instead of `const constString`, to make clear that while the value will not change, it is not determined until run-time, at class or object initialisation (as in Chris’s answer).
- If you want to use the expression as a default value for an optional parameter, it **must** be a true compile-time constant, leaving you two possibilities:

  - Declare an overload, as in Chris’s answer, e.g.:

    `Foo() { Foo(Default); }     Foo(string s) { Bar(s); }`.

    - *This will often be the simpler solution, but could clutter your code and interface if you have many such parameters and thus many overloads, all with documentation comments.*
  - Use `null` as a convention for the default, and interpret that in your method:

    `Foo(string s = null) { Bar(s != null ? s : Default); }`.

    - *This obviously only works if `null` is not a supported parameter to `Foo(string)` and should definitely be clarified in documentation comments.*
  - *Maybe*: apply the `Optional` attribute, as in this question: [behaviour of Optional attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5252389/difference-in-the-behavior-of-optionalattribute-used-to-declare-an-optional-par):

    `Foo([Optional] string s) { Bar(etc.?); }` .

    - *I have not used or studied this – the documentation seemed rather sparse – but it seems tricky and to yield no more than default `= null`, unless perhaps `null` is a supported argument to `Foo(string)`.*

#### References

¹ Language Specification 5.0 §10.5.2.2 10.5.2.2 *Versioning of constants and `static readonly` fields*

² I recall reading this, but have not found it in the Language Specification.

Answer (score 0):

I recently encountered this scenario, and while searching for a solution I stumbled on this page. Based on the example above, I was able to resolve my issue like this:

```
private static readonly String ConStr
 = string.Format("Data Source={0};Initial Catalog={1}; User ID={2}; Password={3};",
                 Properties.Settings.Default.DataSource,
                 Properties.Settings.Default.Catalog,
                 Properties.Settings.Default.UserID,
                 Properties.Settings.Default.Password);
```

Just wanted to share.

Comment: The relevant point here is `readonly` rather than `const` (as suggested in Chris Sinclair’s answer) rather than the call of `String.Format`.

Comment: @PJTrail -  Just to clarify I'm not emphasizing here the String.Format, I overlook the suggestion of Chris Sinclair by the time I posted this answer. Of-course its the readonly.