# Do the [Optional], [In] and [Out] attributes ever affect the behavior of a C# program?

Tags: c#

Do the `[Optional]`, `[In]` and `[Out]` attributes ever affect the behavior of a C# program?

```
    static void F([Optional]string s, [In] int i, [Out] int i2)
    {
    }
```

The attributes appear to do nothing at the C# language level. Is that true in all cases? Is there any relationship to `out` and `ref` parameters?

This question is out of curiosity only. I just found a tool bug where a tool erroneously treated `[Out]` like `out`.

Comment: more info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5252389/difference-in-the-behavior-of-optionalattribute-used-to-declare-an-optional-par

Comment: If don't follow what you mean by [Out] like out but it appears you have an answer that seems to understand the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mainly they affect interop behavior when using P/Invoke or COM.

For purely managed, non COM, code I don't think there is any other behavior changes in the stock .NET libraries.